# How do I create a command to run with sudo?

Tags: bash, unix, path, sudo

I have created a file called `svrestart` in `/home/gab/bin` (which is a folder that should be automatically be added to path on startup) which contains:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

Then I did `chmod +x svrestart` and then I rebooted.

Now if I run `svrestart` I get a permission denied error because I can't have access to these services. If I run `sudo svrestart`, on the other hand, I get:

```
sudo: svrestart: command not found
```

Because the command is hosted in `/home/gab/bin` and the root user probably can't find it.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change these lines accordingly.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

You will be prompted for the `sudo` password for the first command.

Comment: ... unless he's a `sudoer` without password.

Comment: @DanielBeck Isn't there a difference between GNU `sudo` and the one on OS X here? What's to do in this case, actually?

Comment: Run `less /etc/sudoers` and look for `%wheel`, the traditional Unix (?) admin group. There is one line requiring a password, another not requiring it. `%admin`, the OS X group used instead, also requires a password. Edit the file (as `root` of course), add `NOPASSWD` in the `%admin` line, `sudo -k` to invalidate your sudo timestamp (so you'd need to enter your password again even though you entered it only a short time ago), and `sudo ls`. No password required.